# Vector as value in JSON (C++/nlohmann::json)

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I want to have something like that:

```
{ "rooms": [ "room1", "room2", "room3", etc ] }
```

I have an `std::vector<std::string>` of the name of the rooms, and I would like to convert it so the key of the JSON will be 'rooms', and its value will be a list of all the rooms. 
For conclusion, 
How to convert a `std::vector` to JSON array as a value (not a key). 
Thanks for the helpers! :)

Comment: Have you looked at [this part](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#conversion-from-stl-containers) of the documentation where it describes converting a standard library container into a JSON array?

Comment: @NathanPierson Yep, but how to I "attach" the j_vec variable to the the json object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a Json array directly from the `std::vector<std::string>` so something like this will work:

```cpp
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using json = nlohmann::json;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> rooms{
        "room1",
        "room2",
        "room3",
    };

    json j;

    // key `rooms` and create the json array from the vector:
    j["rooms"] = rooms;

    std::cout << j << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
{"rooms":["room1","room2","room3"]}
```

Comment: Oh wow, This is what I did. I didn't think it'll will work.
Thanks!!